# Responsive SVG using Bootstrap

Tags: html, css

Friends, does anyone know which class to use in bootstrap to size svg to small screens?

I don't want to use css for every solution.  I'm sure bootstrap has a solution for this

Comment: [Boostrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/content/images/). Note: they do add this warning - _In Internet Explorer 10 and 11, SVG images with .img-fluid are disproportionately sized._

Answer (score 0):

We can use `img-fluid` class for make image responsive like this :

```
<img src="..." class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
```

**Note :** In Internet Explorer 10 and 11, SVG images with .img-fluid are disproportionately sized. To fix this, add width: 100%; or .w-100 where necessary. This fix improperly sizes other image formats, so Bootstrap doesn’t apply it automatically.

For thumbnail size image, we can use `img-thumbnail` class like this :

```
<img src="..." alt="..." class="img-thumbnail">
```